# Acceso Denegado o error en red al Intentar mostrar archivo

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, tomcat, descarga

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación *Java Web App* montada en *Apache Tomcat 8.0.27*. Tanto en el navegador *Internet Explorer* y *Google Chrome*, me lanzan errores cuando intento mostrar algún archivo que tengo depositado localmente en mi máquina.

Las posibles descargas que puedes realizar en la aplicación son *PDF* o *XML*. Yo lleno dinámicamente una tabla de datos en el que los botones tienen las rutas a los archivos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los botones tienen las siguientes rutas:

**C:\PortalLeal\algun.pdf** ó **C:\PortalLeal\algun.xml**

Pero al momento de darles click a cualquier botón, me lanza los siguientes mensajes de error:

**Este es el mensaje de error en Chrome:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este es el mensaje de error en Internet Explorer:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La forma en la que yo lleno la tabla desde *Java* es esta, donde yo valido si es que en la base de datos el registro tiene: Ambas rutas (PDF, XML), solo la ruta PDF o solo XML, y en base a eso, lleno la tabla:

```
if(null != fac.getRutaPDF() && !fac.getRutaPDF().equalsIgnoreCase("") && null != fac.getRutaXML() && !fac.getRutaXML().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        root.addProperty("accion",
            (null != fac.getRutaPDF() ? "<a onClick=\"downloadURI('"+fac.getRutaPDF().replace("\\", "\\\\")+"','"+nombreFilePDF+"');\" class=\"btn red btn-xs tooltips\"><i class=\"fa fa-file-pdf-o\"></i> PDF</a>" : "") +
            (null != fac.getRutaXML() ? "<a onClick=\"downloadURI('"+fac.getRutaXML().replace("\\", "\\\\")+"','"+nombreFileXML+"');\"  class=\"btn green btn-xs tooltips\"><i class=\"fa fa-file-excel-o\"></i> XML</a>" : "")
        );
    } else if(null != fac.getRutaPDF() && !fac.getRutaPDF().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        root.addProperty("accion",
            (null != fac.getRutaPDF() ? "<a onClick=\"downloadURI('"+fac.getRutaPDF().replace("\\", "\\\\")+"','"+nombreFilePDF+"');\" class=\"btn red btn-xs tooltips\"><i class=\"fa fa-file-pdf-o\"></i> PDF</a>" : "")
        );
    } else if(null != fac.getRutaXML() && !fac.getRutaXML().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        root.addProperty("accion",
            (null != fac.getRutaXML() ? "<a onClick=\"downloadURI('"+fac.getRutaXML().replace("\\", "\\\\")+"','"+nombreFileXML+"');\"  class=\"btn green btn-xs tooltips\"><i class=\"fa fa-file-excel-o\"></i> XML</a>" : "")
        );
    }
```

**Nota:** Me percaté de algunos problemas al intentar mostrar los archivos, por lo que tuve que aplicar el `.replace("\\", "\\\\")` para que la ruta realmente fuera: C:\\PortalLeal\\algun.pdf

Las etiquetas `<a>` ejecutan una rutina en javascript **downloadURI()**, que recibe desde parámetros la ruta completa (`C:\\\\PortalLeal\\\\algun.pdf`), y el nombre del archivo (`algun.pdf`).

```
<script>
    function downloadURI(uri, name) {
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.download = name;
        link.href = uri;
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
        delete link;
    }
</script>
```

(Este método es el que hace la magia para mostrar los archivos)

Realicé una prueba de subir manualmente un archivo a C:\\PortalLeal\\, y manualmente poner la ruta en algún registro de la base de datos y curiosamente algunas veces, sí que muestra el documento (solo en *IExplorer*), y lo muestra de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si el problema lo esté dando *ApacheTomcat* o el navegador web, por los permisos en las carpetas de Windows.

Comment: El problema creo que va más por el browser. Te recomiendo que en lugar de colocar la ruta física de tu archivo, lo que tengas sea un servlet con una URL y que él se encargue de generar la descarga del archivo. El servlet puede tomar el archivo como un parámetro de query string o como parámetros en la URL (path param). Asimismo, este servlet puede estar siempre buscando los archivos de tu ruta `C:/PortalLeal/` u otra ruta configurable (por si luego cambias de carpeta o inclusive de sistema operativo).

Comment: Gracias @LuiggiMendoza investigue un tiempo pasar la URL en un POST en Ajax, pero luego en el servlet no supe muy bien que dato retornar como json y como lanzarlo en javascript o jquery, de casualidad tendrás algún ejemplo? y de igual forma investigare mas a fondo, saludos.

Comment: Espera, ¿estás intentando descargar el archivo mediante ajax? Eso no se puede, los navegadores lo bloquean por problemas de seguridad. Hay librerías que dicen "usar ajax" para la descarga de archivos, pero en realidad lo que hacen es crear un iframe en tu página y allí disparar la descarga (parece ajax pero no lo es).

Comment: Entonces lo que me dices es que realmente puedo solucionar este problema solo enviando la ruta del archivo a un servlet, pero ¿entonces el servlet no retorna nada? ¿mostrar el archivo o descargarlo lo estaría resolviendo completamente java?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15765799/servlet-for-download-files-from-a-specific-folder?rq=1 curiosamente y por asar del destino encontre una liga con un comentario tuyo en el cual me dio una solucion:
(null != fac.getRutaPDF() ? "<a href=\"DownloadServlet?fileName="+nombreFilePDF+"\" class=\"btn red btn-xs tooltips\"><i class=\"fa fa-file-pdf-o\"></i> PDF</a>" : "")

De esta forma recivo en un doGet() el nombre del file y con esto me lanza de forma correcta el pdf! Muchisimas gracias @LuiggiMendoza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias a @LuiggiMendoza pude dar con la solucion:

Primero generar un Servlet para descarga:

```
<servlet>  
    <servlet-name>DownloadServlet</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.al.download.DownloadServlet</servlet-class>  
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>DownloadServlet</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/DownloadServlet</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>
```

Luego en mi clase Java que llena dinámicamente los datos mando llamar de esta forma el Servlet:

```
if(null != fac.getRutaPDF() && !fac.getRutaPDF().equalsIgnoreCase("") && null != fac.getRutaXML() && !fac.getRutaXML().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        root.addProperty("accion",
            (null != fac.getRutaPDF() ? "<a href=\"DownloadServlet?fileName="+nombreFilePDF+"\" class=\"btn red btn-xs tooltips\"><i class=\"fa fa-file-pdf-o\"></i> PDF</a>" : "") +
            (null != fac.getRutaXML() ? "<a href=\"DownloadServlet?fileName="+nombreFileXML+"\" class=\"btn green btn-xs tooltips\"><i class=\"fa fa-file-excel-o\"></i> XML</a>" : "")
        );
    } else if(null != fac.getRutaPDF() && !fac.getRutaPDF().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        root.addProperty("accion",
            (null != fac.getRutaPDF() ? "<a href=\"DownloadServlet?fileName="+nombreFilePDF+"\" class=\"btn red btn-xs tooltips\"><i class=\"fa fa-file-pdf-o\"></i> PDF</a>" : "")
        );
    } else if(null != fac.getRutaXML() && !fac.getRutaXML().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        root.addProperty("accion",
            (null != fac.getRutaXML() ? "<a href=\"DownloadServlet?fileName="+nombreFileXML+"\" class=\"btn green btn-xs tooltips\"><i class=\"fa fa-file-excel-o\"></i> XML</a>" : "")
        );
    }
```

La magia la hace el **?fileName="+nombreFilePDF+"**

Al dar click en automático me manda al servlet:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class DownloadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String fileName = request.getParameter("fileName");
        String filepath = "C:\\PortalLeal\\";
        response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filepath + fileName);

        File file = new File(filepath + fileName);
        if (file.exists()) {
            int i;
            while ((i = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(i);
            }
            fileInputStream.close();
            out.close();
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("uploadPDF.jsp"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No accede porque los recursos (PDF/ XML) están en una carpeta que no es accesible para el **servidor web**.

Todos los recursos que deban mostrarse/usarse en una página web deben ser alcanzables y servibles por el servidor web. Es por eso que las imágenes, archivos css, archivos javascript, etc. usualmente se encuentran en la misma carpeta en la que tienes tus archivos HTML o PHP, porque el servidor web tiene permiso de acceder a todos los archivos dentro de sus carpetas hijos.

Para servir esos archivos PDF y XML, debes ponerlos disponibles para el servidor web ya sea en un servidor web diferente, un endpoint diferente (dentro del mismo servidor), o dentro de las carpetas de la web app que nos muestras.

Comment: por ejemplo, en este caso los xml y pdf los estoy guardando en C:\PortalLeal\algo.pdf o xml, lo que comentas es que los guarde en: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27\temp\15-PortalAcerosLeal\algunaCarpeta, para que mi aplicación tenga acceso a esos archivos? saludos.

Comment: No, lo que tienes que hacer es que servidor realmente "sirva" los archivos, no que los referencias a tu disco duro, que a ojos del browser es lo que está ocurriendo.

Comment: Si en **C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27\temp\15-PortalAcerosLeal\** están tus archivos del sitio web, si funcionará. Ésto es para contestar tu pregunta sobre hacer disponibles los archivos para los usuarios. Ahora debes tomar en cuenta la seguridad de esos archivos ya que pueden ser accesados desde http://misitioweb.com/algunaCarpeta/miarchivo.pdf  por ejemplo

Answer (score 1):

Veo un problema con lo que estás planteando como solución. ¿cual es la idea de desde una aplicación web entregar un link para un archivo en tu disco local (c:)? Ese sistema no te va a servir si alguin más accede, ya que nunca accedera a los archivos.

En resumen, Tomcat no está accediendo al archivo, si no que tu browser y probablemente ahí hay una restricción.

En tu codigo javascript, a la URI agregale un file:// cosa que tu código empiece a crear las URL así:

```
(null != fac.getRutaPDF() ? "<a onClick=\"downloadURI('file://"+fac.getRutaPDF().replace("\\", "\\\\")+"','"+nombreFilePDF+"');\" class=\"btn red btn-xs tooltips\"><i class=\"fa fa-file-pdf-o\"></i> PDF</a>" : "")
```

Igualmente, en mi opnión hacer eso es incorrecto por lo que indicaba antes.